# Test execution in Spring Boot fails due to failed config load

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot

I am trying to test my application and running into troubles:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MainConfiguration.class)
public class ProductionDataRestClientTest {

    @Test
    public void testGetProductionDataAsync() {

    }

}
```

The MainConfiguration class is as follows:

```
@Data
@Configuration
@Slf4j
@PropertySource(value = {
        "classpath:/conf/application.properties", "classpath:/conf/application.build.properties",
        "file:${configPath}/application.properties" }, ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
public class MainConfiguration {

    @Value("${app.configName}")
    private String  configName;

    @Value("${project.name}")
    private String  appName;

    @Value("${project.version}")
    private String  appVersion;

    @Value("${app.historySize}")
    private int     historySize;

    @Value("${app.processOnlyVisibleEnvironments}")
    private Boolean processOnlyVisibleEnvironments;

    @PostConstruct
    private void logConfig() {
        appName = WordUtils.capitalize(appName);
        log.info("constructed config: " + configName);
        log.info(this.toString());
    }
}
```

And the application.properties file is here:

```
app.configName=Internal Classpath
app.historySize=25
app.processOnlyVisibleEnvironments=true

client.timeout.connect=30000
client.timeout.read=30000

threading.pool.size.environmentProcessing=5
threading.pool.size.webServiceRequesting=10
```

My problem is, that Spring seems not to resolve the value identifiers as in normal executions, so the following stacktrace is thrown:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${app.historySize}"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
    at org.springframework.util.NumberUtils.parseNumber(NumberUtils.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor.setAsText(CustomNumberEditor.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertTextValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:464)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:437)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:61)
    ... 47 more
```

I don't have any clue, I tried many different things, nothing worked.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does any of the other specified propertie files (e.g. "file:${configPath}/application.properties") override this setting, by any chance? It's impossible to know why it's failing from the information provided. You may try putting a breakpoint in NumberUtils.java:194 and inspecting the specific value that fails to be converted to a number and then search through your project for it.

Comment: Hey kryger, the value which is tried being parsed is "${app.historySize}". There is no configPath specified, so there are no other files loaded as well. Unfortunately I can't give more information, it seems quite tricky and I don't understand why the String in the @Value annotation isn't interpreted.

Comment: Try with removing all other properties from your configuration. I agree with @kryger some other property is overriding your first property. Also in path should be classpath:conf/application.properties.

Comment: I tried to change the config as well as the PropertySource: @PropertySource(value = { "classpath:/conf/application.properties" }) ... and ... app.configName=Internal Classpath ... app.historySize=25 ... app.processOnlyVisibleEnvironments=true ... Nothing of this worked, still this: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${app.historySize}"

Comment: Maybe it is interesting to know, that the link to a non-existing properties-file throws another exception (@TestPropertySource(locations = { "classpath:/xyz.properties" })): java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [xyz.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Answer (score 2):

There was a very simple way to solve this issue:

```
// To resolve ${} in @Value
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

This has to be a method of the loaded Configuration-file and helps resolving the placeholders.

Thanks for helping ;)